# Bootstrap not working when uploaded

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

It's my first time using bootstrap. I have downloaded version 3.0.3 some time ago which includes some examples and everything works fine on my computer. When I upload the files on the server only firefox displays things as they should be. Every other browser doesn't display things correctly even the examples. I am wondering if there is something i need to configure on the server to make bootstrap work. One of the example pages: http://ppi.com.cy/sfmpatras/examples/theme/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your files is okay. Problem start here

> �C*�C*-group-item">Vestibulum at eros

Its not starting. but closing. so its effecting after that demo content.

Maybe uploaded file encoding problem.

Comment: Yes I figured it out. Turns out there was a problem with the editor I was using which I replaced. Many thanks